# Font not loading properly

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, fonts, font-family

Here is the Ruby on Rails view code

```
<style type="text/css">
    @font-face {
      font-family: 'MyFont';
      src: url('<%= asset_path('pricedown.ttf') %>');
    }

    h1.my-font { 
        font-family: "MyFont", Verdana, Tahoma;
        font-size: 50px;
    }
</style>
<h1 class="my-font">the rascals</h1><hr>
```

The code's output is like this
[image]

The custom Font is of course loaded but I am not getting it like what I saw by opening the actual font file... Actual font file looks like this..
[image]

As you can see, letters like 'h' and 'r' not showing properly.
Is it because I missed something in the CSS part?

Comment: try this  h1.my-font { 
        font-family: 'MyFont', Verdana, Tahoma;
        font-size: 50px;
    }

Comment: Are you sure the version of the font on your computer is exactly the same as the font-face version? Occassionally web versions vary to make it easier for the browser to render.

Comment: @Fags: That didn't work.

Comment: @Coop: Yes. They are same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to fresh download and use the font.

Answer (score 0):

```
h1.my-font { 
    font-family: "MyFont";
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

should work